# Transform a Graphic on Image into Pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

So, I have the following graphic:

[image]

I don't have the point list, so I tried to to the lines "with the eyes" and using the smooth parameter as below:

```
 \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    title={Torque-speed characteristic},
    xlabel={Speed [RPM]},
    ylabel={Torque [N m]},
    xmin=0, xmax=3000,
    ymin=0, ymax=50,
    xtick={0,500,1000,1500,2000,2500,3000},
    ytick={0,10,20,30,40,50},
    legend pos=north east,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
]

\addplot[color=blue, smooth]
    coordinates {
    (0,35)
    (275,43)
    (300,43.76)
    (365,44.50) 
    (400,44.54)
    (500,44)
    (600,40)
    (700,20)
    (750,0)
    };
    \legend{2 poles}

\addplot[color=red,smooth]
    coordinates {
    (0,26.5)
    (600,32)
    (750,33.2)
    (800, 33.7)
    (900, 32.8)
    (950, 15)
    (1000,0)
    };
    \legend{4 poles}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

As can be seen, the lines are not perfect relative to the original graphic. There is a easy way to transform this graphic into a LaTex one? Thanks!

Comment: You can try using e.g. https://automeris.io/WebPlotDigitizer/ to get a list of data points in a file, and then plot that file.

Comment: As an engineer, *I have questions*. You're taking a plot, which was probably interpolated from some measurements, and doesn't show the measurements but a model of what happens between the observed points (or even a best-fit model!) and then you use yet another model to *exactly as humanly possible* replicate it. That has the potential to "lie with plots", as your interpolation might not be the original's interpretation. Maybe the original plot was very concerned with putting the intersections of the lines in the correct places based on the data, and now you'd be concerned with putting the

Comment: maxima in the right places. You don't know who will read that figure and what conclusions they'll draw from it, and whether they'd be right! So, instead of trying to closely replicate **data you don't have**, be honest: use a wide line, use error bars , and don't even try to claim you have the same precision as the original data.

Comment: However, if this is not really about real data, but just about illustrating some principles: well, why are you replicating the figure point-per-point, then? Just draw a figure that illustrates exactly the same principles. There's a relationship between the number of poles and the speed/torque curve, so illustrate that.